# Synchronize KDE4 Hotkeys

Tags: git, kde4

how can I synchronize my personally defined KDE4 Hotkeys between different computers? I would like to check in a file in git, as I do it with `.bashrc` and other configuration files.

I found `.kde/share/config/khotkeysrc` on both machines (Debian Jessie and Ubuntu 14.04). When I compare both files with Kompare, I get about 200 differences, although I have defined a few hotkeys only. Can I still blindly synchronize these files?

I expected something more compact as known from i.e. Fluxbox.

I would appreciate an answer, which incorporates well in Git and avoids files, which I did not create.

Comment: You could try creating a new account, copying that file over, and seeing if the hotkeys are transferred as well?